# How to block access to alarm app, after snooze, from a locked state?

Tags: iphone, ios

Suppose that my iPhone is locked. The alarm rings. Turns out I can tap the alarm snooze notification bubble, and that will take me to the alarm app, where all alarm settings can be read and changed.

This seems like a security hole — I do not wish to allow unlocked access to information in my Alarm app.

What is the best way to block this behavior?